# Load external content with jQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load external content into my `<div id="content">` with Ajax.

This works fine when I have an external navigation outside of my `<div id="content">` as presented below. However I don't need a navigation bar since the whole first page is going to include links to my external pages. How can I:

- Have my links on the homepage (inside the content area) without the external navigation bar.
- Make the content fadeOut each page and fadeIn the next external content inside the content area.

I'm doing something like this: https://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/ and this is what i have so far.

HTML:

```
<a href="Link1">Link1</a>
<a href="Link2">Link2</a>

<div id="content"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').load('home.html');
    $('a').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#content').load(page + '.html');

    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but you can pass fragment url to `load()` method. Maybe it is what you are looking for: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: Why can't you do it like in the link you provided?  They show perfect example?

Comment: Hmm ok let me try to explain it better. The solution in the link i provided works yes, but as soon as there are links loaded in into the content area, such as my homepage that loads on page load with links on it, the links behave like normal links and go to nowhere (error, because of the href is not provide), even when i use "return false;". i want the links on the homepage to behave just like the links outside the content area (load content dynamically to content div) I'm not sure how i can setup an fiddle because my question involves multiple html pages, but i hope this clears some of it up.